# Tripple equals comparision and array length in js

Tags: javascript, underscore.js

Lastly I was skimming through [Underscore.js](http://documentcloud.github.com/underscore/docs/underscore.html) code to learn JavaScript idioms and I found following definition of `each` function:

```
var each = _.each = _.forEach = function(obj, iterator, context) {
    if (obj == null) return;
    if (nativeForEach && obj.forEach === nativeForEach) {
        obj.forEach(iterator, context);
    } else if (obj.length === +obj.length) {
        for (var i = 0, l = obj.length; i < l; i++) {
            if (i in obj && iterator.call(context, obj[i], i, obj) === breaker) return;
        }
    } else {
        for (var key in obj) {
            if (hasOwnProperty.call(obj, key)) {
                if (iterator.call(context, obj[key], key, obj) === breaker) return;
            }
        }
    }
};
```

What this line is for? (I assume that this is a way of checking if passed object is an array, am I right? If so, wouldn't be an `typeof` operator better approach?)

```
obj.length === +obj.length
```

Comment: It seems to be a way of testing if the object has a *length* property that is a number and not NaN. I don't see anywhere in ECMA_262 that the *length* property must be a number, though it makes sense to be one. The function looks faulty as in the middle fork, sparse arrays will fail the `i in obj` test before *length* is reached.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `each` method accepts Collections (Arrays or Objects).

After checking if the native method forEach is available, the method checks if `obj` is an Array. This is not possible using `typeof` since typeof will return `"object"` for arrays as well for objects (try `typeof [] === typeof {}`). So, they used the `obj.length === +obj.length` approach.

This works because if `obj` doesn't have the `length` property, `+obj.length` returns `NaN` and the strict comparison fails. Then, the method assumes `obj` is an `object`.

Answer (score 0):

+obj.length will return a numerical value. === compares the type of the objects and their values. In other words it performs a strict comparison.

http://geekswithblogs.net/brians/archive/2010/07/03/quality-equality-with-javascript-quotquot-gt-quotquot.aspx

Comment: Ok, I understand that lines checks if object has property length, and if this property has numerical value. Thus, why `typeof` operator wasn't used here? Ie. `typeof obj.length === 'number'`?

Answer (score 0):

this line:

```
else if (obj.length === +obj.length) {
```

is necessary because

```
typeof []
```

will return

```
object
```